# AncerstorOrSelf equivalent for user controls

Tags: umbraco

We usually create Razor controls for things like navigation controls, but we're a bit fed up with writing the same code time and time again, so we thought we would create a navigation control wrapped up in a standard user control.

In umbraco Razor views there is a dynamic method AncestorOrSelf which takes an optional Level as a parameter.

Is there an equivalent in the APi that can be used to return a single node?

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [uQuery's](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/) extension method, ['GetAncestorOrSelfNodes()'](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/Content/Nodes#GetAncestorOrSelfNodes%28%29).

> uQuery is an API giving read/write access the Content, Media and Member data, as well as extending the Relations. uQuery originated from uComponents and was added into Umbraco from v4.8.

**Example:**

```
var current = uQuery.GetCurrentNode();
var ancestor = current.GetAncestorOrSelfNodes().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Level == 2);
```

Comment: Fantastic response - all working now, but even more than that - I have realised I should be looking at uQuery a lot more now that it is integrated into the core....thanks Douglas...